# Java Path-finding puzzle game

Tags: java, algorithm

I need some advise in an approach I may need to take to solve a gaming problem which is a puzzle (NxN), the puzzle consists of positive numbers and stored in a two dimensional array. For simplistic reasons is i´ll list a simple example

```
2 1 2 2
1 3 2 1
1 0 2 1
3 1 2 0
```

So the starting point is at (0,0) => 2 and the goal location is to (3,3) => 0
The number in the array location tells you how far to move. (0,0)=> 2 can move to either (0,2) or (2,0) and so on (moves allowed left, right, up, or down)
So you end up with a solution like this for example (0,2)=>(2,2)=>(2,0)=>(3,0)=>(3,3).

so my question is what sort of algorithm i should be looking into and whether any of you have done something similar to this?

Comment: With such a small array I imagine it would be possible to brute force it through recursion.

Comment: @luckydog32 the question does mention this is simple example for the purpose of clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have plenty of solutions here:

- [A* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)
- [Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)
- [Depth-first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)
- [Breadth-first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)

The first two will give you an optimal solution if one exists. A* is typically faster than Dijkstra if the heuristic is well chosen. Breadth- first will also give you an optimal implementation. Depth-first may give you non-optimal solutions in this problem.

The main difference between A* and Djisktra is that A* defines a *heuristic*, namely a function that tries to estimate if a move is better than another one.

The main difference between depth-first and breadth-first is the order in which they explore the space of solutions. Breadth-first will start by looking for all solutions of length 1 then all solutions of length 2, etc, while depth-first will fully explore an entire path until it either cannot go any further or finds a solution.

A* and Dijkstra are typically implemented in imperative style and are probably more sophisticated than the other two, especially A*. Breadth-first is also naturally expressed in imperative style. Depth-first is generally expressed recursively, which can be a problem if your solutions can exceed a length of several thousands moves (depending on the size of your stack, you will generally only be able to make 7-10k recursive calls before you get a `StackOverflowError`).

To sum up:

- A* is generally the most efficient of the algorithms listed below
- A* is the most difficult to implement
- Dijkstra is a special case of A* with similar performance but potentially less efficient
- Breadth-first is straightforward to implement and is resilient to long solutions
- Depth-first is straightforward to implement but it is limited by the length of the longest possible path if it is implemented recursively
- All these algorithms except depth-first guarantee an optimal solution

**Code example:**

I found this [Scala implementation](https://github.com/Dicee/algorithmicProblems/blob/master/codeeval/hard/MinimumPathSum/Main.scala) of A* in one of my repositories. Might help.

Comment: How would you implement A*? It's not obvious to me how to define a valid heuristic function.

Comment: Yeah, just listing options here, I didn't put more thoughts than this into it. The fact of being close of the target doesn't guarantee we'll actually be able to get there, but it might still help to get a speedup

Comment: usually, a heuristic for A* is the straight-line distance to the target (ignoring any obstacles), esp. if it's a navigation problem

Comment: Yes you can apply A* and i already did it with manhatten distance and hamming .

Comment: @Dici: I wonder how would BFS work here as it is used mostly when distance is constant but in OP case it is not. DFS solution will almost be similar to brute force.

Comment: @nomanpouigt mmm makes sense. A "step" in BFS wouldn't actually get closer to the solution and could prevent us from using fast cells (with a high number) allowing to get us close to the objective in a mimimum number of hops.

Answer (score 1):

I have some grid search algorithms (Best-First, Breadth-First, Depth-First) implemented here in Object Pascal (Delphi), that you could easily adapt to Java if this was a classic grid search:

https://github.com/Zoomicon/GridSearchDemo/tree/master/Object%20Pascal/algorithms

You can try the GridSearchDemo application here to see how those algorithms behave when searching in a grid with start and target point and obstacles in various grid cells (you can set them):

https://github.com/Zoomicon/GridSearchDemo/releases

In general, I prefer the A* algorithm, which is an example of a Best-First algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best-first_search)

In your case, this is not a grid really, but a graph, since you seem to have jump links to other cells (or at least this is how you explain the number in your question, although you call it "how far" at first)

Answer (score 0):

I have written a program in java to solve this problem. It uses A*-algorithm with heuristic functions Manhatten and hamming. It depends on the person whether he uses hamming or manhatten distance but Manhatten is better.

Here is my code in java: [8-puzzle](https://github.com/afrazsalim/Gegevens-en-algorithm/tree/master/8-Puzzle-solver/gna-practicum2-2014-2015/gna-practicum2-2014-2015)

Btw it's not an easy approach and many problems can't be solved.